# Glassfish V3 won't start

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

I installed NetBeans 6.8 and tried to run the GlasshFish V3 server.
I'm working under Windows Vista 32 Bits.
First, it won't run. Then I modified the

```
c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

file and put the following line into it:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

And when I run the GlasshFish V3 Server, no error is showing but only "INFOs" are displayed:

```
    3 avr. 2010 19:23:19 com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain main
INFO: Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
Welcome to Felix
================
INFO: Perform lazy SSL initialization for the listener 'http-listener-2'
INFO: Starting Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-k - Sat Apr 03 19:23:24 CEST 2010
INFO: Starting Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-k - Sat Apr 03 19:23:25 CEST 2010
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-k started in: 423ms listening on port 35127
INFO: GlassFish v3 (74.2) startup time : Felix(4456ms) startup services(1709ms) total(6165ms)
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-k started in: 459ms listening on port 35116
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-k started in: 428ms listening on port 35155
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-k started in: 470ms listening on port 35160
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-k started in: 513ms listening on port 35159
INFO: javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.classLoaderProvider = org.glassfish.weld.WeldActivator$GlassFishClassLoaderProvider@5be8f4
INFO: Hibernate Validator bean-validator-3.0-JBoss-4.0.2
INFO: Binding RMI port to *:35165
INFO: Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
INFO: JMXStartupService: Started JMXConnector, JMXService URL = service:jmx:rmi://PC-de-Charlotte:35165/jndi/rmi://PC-de-Charlotte:35165/jmxrmi
INFO: Using com.sun.enterprise.transaction.jts.JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate as the delegate
INFO: [Thread[GlassFish Kernel Main Thread,5,main]] started
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-k started in: 150ms listening on port 35159
INFO: Perform lazy SSL initialization for the listener 'http-listener-2'
INFO: {felix.fileinstall.poll (ms) = 5000, felix.fileinstall.dir = C:\Program Files\sges-v3\glassfish\modules\autostart, felix.fileinstall.debug = 1, felix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start = true, felix.fileinstall.tmpdir = C:\Users\CHARLO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\fileinstall-330907148519261411, felix.fileinstall.filter = null}
INFO: {felix.fileinstall.poll (ms) = 5000, felix.fileinstall.dir = C:\Users\Charlotte\.netbeans\6.8\GlassFish_v3\autodeploy\bundles, felix.fileinstall.debug = 1, felix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start = true, felix.fileinstall.tmpdir = C:\Users\CHARLO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\fileinstall-2938963288421854459, felix.fileinstall.filter = null}
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-k started in: 95ms listening on port 35160
INFO: Updating configuration from org.apache.felix.fileinstall-autodeploy-bundles.cfg
INFO: Installed C:\Program Files\sges-v3\glassfish\modules\autostart\org.apache.felix.fileinstall-autodeploy-bundles.cfg
INFO: {felix.fileinstall.poll (ms) = 5000, felix.fileinstall.dir = C:\Users\Charlotte\.netbeans\6.8\GlassFish_v3\autodeploy\bundles, felix.fileinstall.debug = 1, felix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start = true, felix.fileinstall.tmpdir = C:\Users\CHARLO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\fileinstall-6474085409014899009, felix.fileinstall.filter = null}
```

And there is no message such as "Glassfish started"!
So, when I try to access to the admin web interface:

```
localhost:4848 or localhost:8080 or localhost:8181
```

, It doesn't work.

What should I do?

Thank you very much,
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

In Netbeans right-click the Glassfish Server which has the issue, and select

```
View Domain Server log
```

Open a command-line window and navigate to a "bin" directory of the Glassfish installation where your "asadmin" executable is located. In the command window type

```
asadmin start-domain --verbose
```

And wait for the server to start, while the server starts look at the Output pane in the Glassfish IDE window. After everything starts, try restarting **from the Netbeans IDE**. Look at the command-line window and it should have a messa stating that the **DAS has been stopped**.

Close the command-line window. If the restart fails, try undeploying all applications before the restart from Netbeans.